# Remotely Executing an Independent .exe on an Apache Server [CGI]

Tags: windows, perl, apache, cgi, executable

I have an executable program I've created which is a server. I would like to be able to start and stop instances of this program on a Windows Server 2008 machine via the website the same machine hosts.

The functionality I'm hoping to achieve is: from anywhere I can access my website to start and stop instances of the server code instead of constantly Remote Desktop-ing into it just to start/stop it.

I've tried using Perl, but when I run the code it looks like it prints out some of the information the program does (so it's working) but then seems to stop. Whereas I would like it to start an instance of the program as its own process.

Perl:

```
#!C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

exec('C:\file.exe');
```

I'm not sure what language I should be using or if there are completely other, better ways of achieving my goal. Thanks!

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html

Comment: I appreciate the link, but I was hoping more of a response that was a little more analytic of the goals, in the terms that is Perl the correct method of trying to do what I was looking for?

As I mentioned, instead of using threads spawning a completely new process, and then killing the process if it's active.

Thanks.

Comment: Threads are very hard to work with, believe me... To do it right and to understand it correctly, you need a lot of study about that. I know you don't like to hear that, but **threads** are really special part, not just anything else. Sorry if you hate me now :-/

Comment: Of course I don't hate you! :) But I'm very familiar with threads, the server I'm trying to manipulate here is very thread heavy. I'm just hesitant because all I'm trying to do is:

1. Click a button that starts an .exe
2. Allow another button to kill processes with that name on host

It just seems unnecessary and a lot of overkill to try and implement it with threading. (Though of course I could be wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec` is the wrong choice, and so are threads. Simply [start the process in the background](http://p3rl.org/Proc%3a%3aBackground). You did not say how you would normally stop the server. If it has its own command for stopping, the same as for starting applies; else [`kill`](http://p3rl.org/kill) the process.